# In VB.NET use a textbox as a log for which if statement it is beeing proccesed inside a sub

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Hi i have a Sub that has multiple if statements in it.
Each if statement has a large loop that searches for specific files and text inside files.
I tried various ways to use a text box in order to get the information which if is currently proccessing at the time and i see that for some reason the ui is not refreshed until the sub finishes and so i see everytime in the textbox the last proceesed if message.
What do you think is the best way to handle it?
I hope that this has nothing to do with threads because threads are something that i am not familiar with !

Comment: This is because you are performing the operation on the UI thread.  You need to separate the longer running operation into it's own task or thread.  I'll just find a decent guide for you, one moment

Comment: This article outlines the concept reasonably well: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33280.vb-net-invoke-method-to-update-ui-from-secondary-threads.aspx

Comment: This is also a useful guide to using a BackgroundWorker to achieve a similar outcome: https://thedeveloperblog.com/vbnet/backgroundworker-vbnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
Public Sub logWithCrLf(tx As TextBox, s As String)
    tx.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)
    tx.Select(tx.TextLength - 1, 0)
    tx.ScrollToCaret()
    tx.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I see that it scrolls a bit smoother using `tx.AppendText(s)` than `tx.Text &= s`, which scrolls up to 0 then down to caret again.

(I write this as an answer to contribute with the `tx.AppendText()` recommendation)

Comment: `AppendText` already scrolls by itself, so you don't need the three lines below it.  Do favor `Environment.NewLine` over `vbCrLf`

Answer (score 0):

I think using Application.DoEvents() is an easy choice. But I don't know if that would be the desired behavior.
If the use of Application.DoEvents() fails, another thread should handle it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=netframework-3.5

Comment: In general, it is recommended not to use `DoEvents()` apart from in specific circumstances.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/2169762) and the caution box at the end of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents)

Comment: @Martin as i understand i have to use such backround workers as much are my if statements right ?

Comment: @TedKon I would suggest that any non-UI code should be separate (although this will sometimes depend upon the delay to run that code).  A background worker is one way of achieving it.  Or a Thread, or a Task, and there are others